# TouchListener for frameLaout

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout containing couple of views. And I want to set TouchListener to the frameLayout, the layout is created in code:

```
FrameLayout textLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            textLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams textLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            textLayout.setLayoutParams(textLayoutParams);
            container.addView(textLayout);
```

I assgined it a touchListener but it doesnt enter it.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("tag","touch");
        return true;
    }
```

Update:
I think I found part of the problem : I set the background of the frameLayout to green and expanded the space of the framelayout takes so that it would not cover only its view, but a little more. So I saw my views and by their side a green color. when I touched the green color the onTouch event activates, but not when I touched the views.

Comment: Can you show more of the code? It's difficult to know what would could be wrong with what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using your fragment as listener. Please make sure it implements and overrides, i.e.

```
public final MyFragment implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ....
}
```

And then ensure you are not using the touch listener in your activity or other fragment/view where you return `true`, i.e. touch event is consumed and won't be dispatched onward.

**Note** For the event to be dispatched properly even if there are views in the frame layout container, you can set them as non-clickable, i.e.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    ...>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:clickable="false" .../>
    <... android:clickable="false" .../>
</FrameLayout>
```

You can disable all views as clickable objects in code too if you need:

> text.setClickable(false);

Comment: it does implements it

Comment: @SagiCohen Are you using touch listeners on other places? Or `GestureDetector` implementations?